# Infinitescroll plugin not triggered in combination with Isotope

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to make [infinitescroll](https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll) work together with [isotope](https://github.com/desandro/isotope). I've been through the docs and page sources but cannot find the problem. I do see the first items that are initially on the page, but upon scrolling to the very bottom of the page, nothing happens.

My HTML includes a link to the next page (a paginated blog page):

```
<nav id='page-nav'>
  <a href='/blog/full-blog?page=2'></a>
</nav>
```

The JavaScript:

```
  $("#container").isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    isAnimated: true
  });

  $("#container").infinitescroll({
    navSelector: '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
    nextSelector: '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
    itemSelector: '.item',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
    debug: true,
    },
    function( newElements ) {
      console.log(newElements);
      $("#container").isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
    }
  );
```

When viewing my page, the console says:

```
["determinePath", Array[2]]
 jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
["Binding", "bind"] jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
["math:", 497, 451] jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
["math:", 0, 451] jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
["heading into ajax", "/blog/full-blog?page=2"] jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
Using HTML via .load() method jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:4567/blog/full-blog?page=2". jquery.js:8240
["Error", "end"] jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:1
["Binding", "unbind"]
```

Can anyone explain me what the last two lines mean? Obviously there is an error, but what does end mean? Are there no more pages to load? In my example I have 3 pages with more items to load. Unbind, is the scroll event unbind? Can't find any docs/info about the error logs...

Answer (score 0):

The line 'heading into ajax' means an ajax request was fired on reaching the bottom.

'XHR Finished Loading' means the ajax request was successful.

'Error' in the 2nd last line means there was no data returned by the ajax request. Make sure the page you are making request to doesnt return empty result. To check, open '/blog/full-blog?page=2' in the browser.